# Can you call Wait() on a task multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, wait

I want to run initializations of some objects asynchronously, but some objects depend on others being initialized. And then all objects need to be initialized before the rest of my application continues.

Is it possible to call Wait() on a task and later call Wait() on it again, or as in my example WaitAll() on a collection where it is included?

```
Dictionary<String, Task> taskdict = new Dictionary<String, Task>( );

   taskdict.Add( "Task1",
        Task.Factory.StartNew( ( ) => {
         //Do stuff
        } ) );

   taskdict.Add( "Task2",
        Task.Factory.StartNew( ( ) => {
          taskdict[ "Task1" ].Wait( );

         //Do stuff

        } ) );

      try {
        Task.WaitAll( taskdict.Values.Convert<Task[ ]>( ) );
      }
```

Or will that second Wait() / WaitAll() fail?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You most certainly can wait on a task twice.  You can wait on a task as many times as you want with no negative side effects.  Now, if you've already waited on a task in that same thread it will already be done, so the future `Wait` calls will all just return immediately as there is nothing to wait for, but they certainly won't fail or otherwise produce inappropriate results.

Note that if a task didn't complete normally and was instead cancelled or couldn't finish as a result of an exception being thrown then calling `Wait` will re-throw the exception (each time you call `Wait`).  If `Wait` is throwing exceptions for you, there's a chance that that is the reason.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer. And for the detail on the Exception handling. That is one important issue I must consider.

Comment: @Servy what if I want the Task to re run, on second wait. How can I invalidate task result?

Comment: @MerdanGochmuradov You can't.  That's not how tasks work.

Comment: @Servy - what can I do to rerun a failed task?  Do I need to copy the failed task into a new unstarted task and wait on the new task? If so, how do I copy a failed task into a new uninitiated task?

Comment: @barrypicker That's going to depend on what that `Task` represented.  There's no general case way to create a new `Task` that conceptually represents re-running it.

Comment: what about resources? is `await task` when the task is complete comparable to running a simple boolean check

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Yes.  The `Task` has an `IsCompleted` boolean, so when you `await` it it's simply checking that, and because it'll return `true`, it'll just keep on going.